# Error in downloading Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I tried following command to install django

```
 pip install -e django/
```

I am getting following error:

```
django/ should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with 
    svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+
```

I am using Windows 32 bit

Comment: Remove **-e**. Here is the documentation: `  -e Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.`

Comment: Why do you have a trailing slash  there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just try to run `pip install django`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the -e, nor the final /. Do this:

```
pip install django
```